# How to Get Current Pod in Kubernetes Java Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes

I am deploying my Microservices on Kubernetes Cluster. Every Application has 4 replicas or PODS. For a REST API in 1 application, I want to track which POD addressed my request. e.g. my `/app/deploy(body contains app_id)` request is handled by `POD1`.

For the same, I have imported Kubernetes jar in my application. In my code, I want to check the current POD on which this code is running.
I want an API like `kubernetesDiscoveryClient.getCurrentPOD()`, something of this sort.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
podName = Optional.ofNullable(System.getenv("HOSTNAME"));
```

Comment: That's disrespectful to mark your own stolen answer as correct.

Answer (score 27):

You do not need Kubernetes Jar in your Java application. A simple `System.getenv("HOSTNAME")` will give you the name of your Pod. Works on all platform, and since Kubernetes version 1.6 at least.

More formally, you could use the following in your Kube spec ([detailed reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/#use-pod-fields-as-values-for-environment-variables)), and then read the environment using `System.getenv("MY_POD_NAME")` in Java.

```
 env:
 - name: MY_POD_NAME
   valueFrom:
     fieldRef:
       fieldPath: metadata.name
```

Answer (score 8):

Every pod has a `hostname` same as `pod_name`. So what you can do is, write an api which return you `hostname`.

Example:

**in Java**
`java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost();`

**in C#**
`System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME");`

Comment: `COMPUTERNAME` seems to be Windows. On Linux servers, it seems to be `HOSTNAME`. Better try both for multi-environment applications.