# GET URL Name in Kubernetes

Tags: spring-boot, devops, knative

I use spring boot project and deployed in Kubernetes, I would like to get URL of the pod,

I referred [How to Get Current Pod in Kubernetes Java Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51593129/how-to-get-current-pod-in-kubernetes-java-application) not worked for me.

There are different environments (DEV, QA, etc..) and wanted to get URL dynamically, is there anyway?

my service yaml

```
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1alpha1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        autoscaling.knative.dev/metric: concurrency
        # Disable scale to zero with a minScale of 1.
        autoscaling.knative.dev/minScale: "1"
        # Limit scaling to 100 pods.
        autoscaling.knative.dev/maxScale: "100"
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: testImage
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
```

is it possible to add

```
valueFrom:
     fieldRef:
     fieldPath: status.podIP
```

from url https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/#the-downward-api

Comment: You don't have the example environment variable from the docs you linked in your example. Did you try it?

Comment: Before that, I'd like to know ```kind: Pod``` in the example but mine is service.

Comment: What do you think that would do? A service doesn't run anything so there is nothing to expose to.

Answer (score 0):

Your case is about Knative ingress, and not Kubernetes.

From the inbound network connectivity part of the [runtime contract of the knative documentation](https://github.com/knative/serving/blob/master/docs/runtime-contract.md#inbound-network-connectivity):

> In addition, the following base set of HTTP/1.1 headers MUST be set on
>   the request:
>
> - Host - As specified by RFC 7230 Section 5.4
>
> Also, the following proxy-specific request headers MUST be set:
>
> - Forwarded - As specified by RFC 7239.

Look to the headers inside your request.

An example for servlet `doGet` method:

```
Enumeration<String> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
while(headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
  String paramName = (String)headerNames.nextElement();
  out.print("<tr><td>" + paramName + "</td>\n");
  String paramValue = request.getHeader(paramName);
  out.println("<td> " + paramValue + "</td></tr>\n");
}
```