# Trying to understand application logging best practice in a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, logback

Considering a `K8s` cluster has 3 `pods`, each has a docker container of `same` `SpringBoot` app providing web services, with `LogBack` as logging solution.

Log path for each Spring Boot app is the same, and each application will do the same file logging, defined in `application.properties`. I wonder if without any `volume` configuration, is it going to cause `locking situation` so that each Spring Boot app will try to write to the same file at same time?

If above speculation is true, what is the best practice? Below is what I can think of

1. Create different `volume` for each pod so logging file write to different physical location. I think it is an overkill for logging
2. Generate unique file name `suffix` so app log file name for each application is different. Simply can be just cut off of pod name. However this solution requires to pass dynamic parameters to the pod -> container -> application

Comment: Its good to use ELK stack . I think logstash will work . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57399354/send-spring-boot-logs-directly-to-logstash-with-no-file

Comment: You don't have to pass anything to your application explicitly to get the name of the pod it's running in. Just use the existing environment variable.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51594557/4571544

Comment: If you have to log to a file I would go for option 2), i.e using some kind of suffix. However, I would recommend to take a look at centralized log aggregation tools like Splunk or Graylog and e.g have a log appender sending the logs directly to that tool without logging to a file. More options can be found here https://landscape.cncf.io/card-mode?category=logging&grouping=category